# java - find h, s, and b of hsb color

Tags: java, colors, applet

I am making an HSB color picker. You can enter in the hue, saturation, brightness of a color, and it will make a small square the color you entered. Now I am allowing the user to save the color, which works, but I want it so that when you press the 'Open Color' button the h, s, and b text input boxes display the h, s, and b values of the saved color. Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends Applet implements ActionListener, java.io.Serializable {
private Rectangle color;
Random randomColor = new Random();
TextField one;
TextField two;
TextField three;
Button enter;
Button random;
Button save;
Button open;
String hvalue="255";
String svalue="0";
String bvalue="255";
Color hsb = Color.getHSBColor(Integer.parseInt(hvalue), Integer.parseInt(bvalue), Integer.parseInt(svalue));

int width = 320;
int height = 260;
String version = "0.0.1";
String name = "Color Picker"; 


public void init() {
    setSize(width, height); 
    Frame c = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    c.setTitle(name + " - Version " + version);
    setLayout(null);
    color = new Rectangle(width/2-32, 20, 64, 64);

    one = new TextField("", 15);
    one.setBounds(width/2-60, height-120, 40, 20);
    add(one);
    two = new TextField("", 15);
    two.setBounds(width/2-20, height-120, 40, 20);
    add(two);
    three = new TextField("", 15);
    three.setBounds(width/2+20, height-120, 40, 20);
    add(three);
    enter = new Button("Enter");
    enter.setBounds(width/2-50, height-80, 100, 20);
    add(enter);
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    random = new Button("Random Color");
    random.setBounds(width/2-50, height-60, 100, 20);
    add(random);
    random.addActionListener(this);
    save = new Button("Save Color");
    save.setBounds(width/2-50, height-40, 100, 20);
    add(save);
    save.addActionListener(this);
    open = new Button("Open Color");
    open.setBounds(width/2-50, height-20, 100, 20);
    add(open);
    open.addActionListener(this);
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(hsb);
    g2.fill(color);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == enter) {
        hvalue = one.getText();
        svalue = two.getText();
        bvalue = three.getText();
        try {
            hsb = Color.getHSBColor(Integer.parseInt(hvalue), Integer.parseInt(bvalue), Integer.parseInt(svalue));
            repaint();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    else if (evt.getSource() == random) {
        hvalue = String.valueOf(randomColor.nextInt(200));
        svalue = String.valueOf(randomColor.nextInt(200));
        bvalue = String.valueOf(randomColor.nextInt(200));
        one.setText(hvalue);
        two.setText(svalue);
        three.setText(bvalue);
        try {
            hsb = Color.getHSBColor(Integer.parseInt(hvalue), Integer.parseInt(bvalue), Integer.parseInt(svalue));
            repaint();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    else if (evt.getSource() == save) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/C:/Users/Barbara/Downloads/color.color");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(hsb);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else if (evt.getSource() == open) {
        Color openhsb = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/C:/Users/Barbara/Downloads/color.color");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            openhsb = (Color) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            try {
                hsb = openhsb;
                repaint();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        } catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Should I save the h, s, and b values to the color1.color file? I don't know how, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the converters provided by the `Color` class:

```
Color color = Color.red;
float [] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
```

or

```
Color color = Color.red;
float [] hsb = new float[3];
Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), hsb);
```

the values retured are between 0 and 1. So you would probably want to multiply them by 360 to allow them to fit your programs model.

[Javadoc for RGBtoHSB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D%29)

Comment: so Color color would equal openhsb?

Comment: Yes, you can just store a `Color` object and when you need to get the hsb you can then convert it using the `RGBtoHSB` method. However if you need to access the hsb values often (maybe in a drawing thread) then you might store the values and update them when you change the color.